# Using given comparator to find minimum of template objects in a given range

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, comparator

I am implementing a class that stores a vector of template objects. The goal is to find a minimum in a given range using either default `std::less` comparator or an optional comparator passed in the constructor's parameter. The passed comparator is a functor, function or a lambda function.

How can I use the given comparator to find the minimum in a given range (set by two iterators) of the objects?

I know, that the objects have implemented overloaded `operator<`. I tried to use `std::min_element()` from the STL, but was not able to do it right.

Thank you. I have updated my code, but the lambda expression below is still not accepted. It is part of my homework, so it has to pass several asserts. Sorry for the length.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <functional>


using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename MyComparator = std::less<T>> // optional comparator
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass ( ) = default;

    template<typename MyIterator>
    MyClass ( MyIterator start, MyIterator end,  MyComparator comparator ) : m_comparator ( comparator )
    {
        for ( MyIterator it = start; it != end; it++ )
            m_objects.push_back ( * it );        
    }
    
    template<typename MyIterator>
    MyClass ( MyIterator start, MyIterator end )
    {
        for ( MyIterator it = start; it != end; it++ )
            m_objects.push_back ( * it );
    }

    template<typename MyIterator>
    T min ( MyIterator from, MyIterator to )
    {
        if ( from == to )
            throw invalid_argument ("Invalid");
        auto result = std::min_element ( from, to, m_comparator );
        return *result;
    }   
  typename vector<T>::iterator begin() { return m_objects.begin(); }
  typename vector<T>::iterator end() { return begin() + m_objects.size(); }
  size_t size () const { return m_objects.size(); }
  void push_back ( const T & elem ) { m_objects.push_back ( elem ); }
  void pop_back ( ) { m_objects.pop_back( ); }

private:
   MyComparator m_comparator;
   // function<bool(T, T)> m_comparator;  This is not working.
    vector <T> m_objects;
    typename vector<T>::iterator const_iterator;
};
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class CompareClass
{
  public:
               CompareClass ( bool byLength = true ) 
      : m_ByLength ( byLength ) 
    { 
    }
    bool       operator () ( const string & a, const string & b ) const 
    { 
      return m_ByLength ? a . length () < b . length () : a < b;
    }
  private:
    bool       m_ByLength;  
};
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool CompareFun ( const string & a, const string & b )
{
  return strcasecmp ( a . c_str (), b . c_str () ) < 0;
}

int main ( )
{
  vector<string> words { "abc", "iff", "voo", "STACK" };

  MyClass <string> a ( words . begin (), words . end () );
  assert ( a . min ( a . begin (), a . end () ) ==  "STACK" );  // OK

  MyClass <string, bool(*)(const string &, const string &)> b ( words . begin (), words . end (), CompareFun );
  assert ( b . min ( b . begin (), b . end () ) == "abc" ); // OK

  MyClass <string, CompareClass> c ( words . begin (), words . end (), CompareClass ( false ) );
  assert ( c . min ( c . begin (), c . end () ) == "STACK" ); // OK

/* MyClass <string, function<bool(const string &, const string &)> > d ( [] ( const string & a, const string & b )
  {
    return a > b;
  } );
  for ( const auto & w : words )
    d . push_back ( w );
*/

// assert ( d . min ( d . begin (), d . end () ) == "voo" ); // Fail

/* I am not able to figure out how to accept lamba expression
 into MyClass member template variable (m_comparator). */
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: you wrote too much code at once. Frankly, there are so many errors that I dont know where to start (https://godbolt.org/z/eE3daK6Yv). To find the minimum element in a vector you can use [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in the code you have shown:

1. defaulting `typename MyComparator` to the wrong type.  `T` is the vector element type, not a comparator type.
2. applying `= default` to a templated constructor.  You applied `template<typename MyIterator>` to the wrong constructor.
3. missing `template<typename MyIterator>` on `findMin()`.  For that matter, why is `findMin()` taking iterators at all, and ignoring the `vector` its constructor populated?
4. not specifying template arguments when instantiating `MyClass` objects.
5. not instantiating an object of `MyCompareClass` when passing it to `MyClass`.
6. not declaring the members of `MyCompareClass` as `public`.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename MyComparator = std::less<T>> // optional comparator
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass ( ) = default;

    template<typename MyIterator>
    MyClass ( MyComparator comparator, MyIterator start, MyIterator end ) : m_comparator ( comparator )
    {
        for ( MyIterator it = start; it != end; it++ )
        {
            m_objects.push_back ( * it );
        }
    }

    template<typename MyIterator>
    T findMin ( MyIterator from, MyIterator to )
    {
        auto result = std::min_element ( from, to, m_comparator );
        return *result;
    }

private:
    MyComparator m_comparator;
    vector<T> m_objects;
};

//====================================================================================

bool MyStringComparator ( const string & first, const string & second )
{
    return strcasecmp ( first. c_str (), second.c_str() ) < 0;
}

//====================================================================================

struct MyCompareClass 
{
    MyCompareClass () = default;
    bool operator () ( const MyObject &obj1, const MyObject &obj2 ) const
    {
        return ...;
    }
};

// ========================================================

int main()
{
    // 1.
    vector <string> vec { "Hello", "World", "How", "Are", "You", "Fine", "Thanks" };
    MyClass<string, decltype(&MyStringComparator)> a ( &MyStringComparator,  vec.begin(), vec.end() );

    auto result = a.findMin ( vec.begin() + 1, vec.begin () + 3 ); /* I need to find a minimum in a given range of any objects */ 
   
    // 2. 
    vector <MyObject> anotherVec { MyObject_1, MyObject_2, MyObject_3, ... };
    MyClass<MyObject, MyCompareClass> b  ( MyCompareClass{}, anotherVec.begin(), anotherVec.end() );
    auto result_2 = b.findMin ( anotherVec.begin(), anotherVec.end() );

    // etc..
 
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/bK0u1s)

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my code, but the lambda expression below is still not accepted. It is part of my homework, so it has to pass several asserts. Sorry for the length.

Comment: @JosefMalek not accepted how exactly? By the compiler? By your instructor? What kind of asserts exactly?

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you.